# Make a Download Button act like an Add To Cart Button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I link a simple download button act like a cart button ? If I have to make a user download a 2$ song, instead of directly downloading it, it should add that song to the woo commerce cart page.

Comment: please be more specific add code

Comment: <form method="get" action="file.mp3">
         <button type="submit">    
             <img src="http://smcq.3.previewmydevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Download.png" >
          </button>  
</form>

It's just a simple button which downloads the mp3 file, but Instead I want that download button to add the mp3 file to the shopping cart as a product and then the user should check out using PayPal or anything.

Comment: So you want to replace text of the "Add to Cart" button to "Download"?

Comment: Not the text. Just The functionality. Clicking the download button should act the same as clicking "Add to cart" button.

Comment: What's the difference? If your change the button text to "Download" you got a Download button and functionality of Add to Cart as well. Isn't that right?

Comment: I don't have a woo commerce product page. I just have one mp3 file which is being displayed on a custom page. If I replace the text to download, it won't add anything to the cart page. Because the add to cart button is only displayed on the products page. I don't have a products page. I am using that mp3 file on my home page for selling.

Answer (score 1):

In woocommerce add your product. And in the product edit page there is a checkbox called 'downloadable'. Tick that box.  Then it will become a downloadable product. That item will be added to cart.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme's `functions.php` to change "Add to Cart" to "Download"

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );

function woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {      
    return __( 'Download', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want a custom **Add To Cart** or **Download** button, add the following link to that button

```
http://your-domain.com/?add_to_cart=5
```

Where `your-domain` is your site domain and `5` is your product/audio ID.